# Look! Smoke! Who do we blame?

Tags: c++, performance

Recently, I found a way to generate specific blame for [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org). That was cool, so I decided to make a C++ program for it. I also have it on [GitHub](https://github.com/ejxct/Blame-bot/tree/bc3d91750c0a585b8a32e36c7fde748c4d3f9546). This program is called Blame Bot.

Blame Bot does not need any flags to compile, so you can use `make blame` to compile it.

## How it works:

Blame Bot takes an input of a number. This input is your chat id. This number is taken from your chat link. Mine would be: https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/301688/grant-garrison, and my number would be 301688. Then, the number is converted to base 7. A switch statement then outputs the characters. (Note: the characters must be in double quotes.)

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int digit;
    std::string stringDigit, answer, instring;
    std::cin>>instring;
    int in = std::stoi(instring,nullptr);
    while (in != 0){
        digit = in % 7;
        if (digit < 10){
            stringDigit = '0' + digit;
        }else{
            stringDigit = digit - 10 + 'A';
        }
            answer = stringDigit + answer;
            in /= 7;
    }
    std::cout<<"!!/blame\u180E ";
    int i = 0;
    while(answer.length()>=i){
        switch (answer[i]-'0'){
            case 0: std::cout<<"\u180E";
                break;
            case 1: std::cout<<"\u200B";
                break;
            case 2: std::cout<<"\u200C";
                break;
            case 3: std::cout<<"\u200D";
                break;
            case 4: std::cout<<"\u2060";
                break;
            case 5: std::cout<<"\u2063";
                break;
            case 6: std::cout<<"\uFEFF";
                break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    std::cout<<"a\n";
}
```

## What I'm looking for:

I'm looking for efficiency and syntax improvements. I know the program is fast already, but any extra computation cut out is a bonus. I do want to leave the `{` and `}` on the `if` statements though, as I think it improves readability for me. I also do not want to use any libraries.

## What I think can be improved:

I think that switching back and forth from `std::string` and `int` is inefficient, and I'm sure there is a better way that doesn't need that. I also think that the base conversion algorithm might have a better replacement.

Comment: The network is going to be your bottleneck anyway; why do you worry about int to string conversion overhead?

Comment: @tripleee I'm not planning on using this very much. If I need to do something that uses the same principles as this in the future (which I most likely will), efficiency is always helpful. Plus, why not?

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but what is the purpose of this program?

Comment: @MartinR it essentially creates a string that is used by another program to create a custom message. Or, put more simply, it encodes your user id so that another program can decode it.

Comment: `you can use make blame to compile it.` There does not seem to be a makefile anywhere, not even on the github. Did you forget to upload it?

Comment: @yuri: The built-in makerules are sufficient, you can compile the program on the command line with `make blame` without a makefile (assuming GNU make). – Did you change your profile in response to this question?

Comment: @MartinR I just think that having an explicit build process/command is better practice than hoping `make` will do the right thing. Unsure what you mean about the profile change.

Comment: @yuri: Agreed. – I just wondered about the `᠎᠎᠎᠎᠎...` in your profile page, because `᠎` happens to be `"\u180E"` which is used in the above program.

Comment: @MartinR That is a complete coincidence. I only updated my profile once and that was some time ago.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Spacing

The usage of (horizontal) space is not consistent, you have a space
after `if` and `switch`, but not after `else` and `while`. 
I would generally use more whitespace to increase the readability, in particular after keywords, around operators, etc. For example

```
while (answer.length() >= i) {
```

#### Scope

It is a good habit to declare variables at the narrowest scope where they are used, and not at the top of the function. This applies for example
to `digit` and `stringDigit`, which are only used inside the while-loop.

#### Input validation

`std::stoi(instring, nullptr)` silently ignores leading whitespace
and trailing non-digits, that might or might not be wanted.
The `pos` parameter could be used to check if the complete string
has been converted successfully.

Also `std::stoi(instring, nullptr)` throws an `std::invalid_argument`
exception if the input string contains no valid digits at all,
you might want to catch that.

#### Iterating too far

In

```
int i = 0;
while(answer.length()>=i){
    switch (answer[i]-'0'){
        // ...
    }
    i++;
}
```

the last iteration accesses `answer[answer.length()]`, which is
the null character. Even if this causes no harm (`answer[i]-'0'`
then matches none of the cases) it is probably unintended and you'll
want `answer.length() > i` instead. (See below for further improvements
of this part.)

#### Simplifications

The remainder modulo 7 *cannot* be `>= 10`, so the while loop
simplifies to

```
while (in != 0) {
    int digit = in % 7;
    std::string stringDigit;
    stringDigit = '0' + digit;
    answer = stringDigit + answer;
    in /= 7;
}
```

which can further be simplified to

```
while (in != 0) {
    char digit = '0' + in % 7;
    answer.insert(0, 1, digit);
    in /= 7;
}
```

making the `stringDigit` variable obsolete, and mutating `answer`
instead of concatenating strings.

Iterating over all valid string indices is better done with a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < answer.length(); ++i) {
    // ... use `answer[i]` ...
}
```

But actually you don't need the index, only the characters, and
iterating over all characters in a string can be done more simply
with a range-based for loop (added in C++ 11):

```
for (char& c : answer)
    // ...
}
```

The switch statement can be replaced by an array lookup:

```
std::string blameStrings[] = {
    "\u180E", "\u200B", "\u200C", "\u200D", "\u2060", "\u2063", "\uFEFF"
};
for (char& c : answer) {
    std::cout << blameStrings[c - '0'];
}
```

(You can probably choose a better name for the array, but I have no
idea what those strings stand for.)

#### Get rid of the intermediate string storage

Your code computes `answer` as the base-7 representation of the
input number, and then iterates over the characters in that string.

The conversion from digits to characters in a string and back to
digits can be avoided by storing the integer digits in a vector
instead. And instead of prepending additional digits, we can append
them (to avoid that memory needs to be moved repeatedly) and then iterate
over the result in reverse order:

```
#include <vector>

// ...

int in = std::stoi(instring, nullptr);
std::vector<int> digits;
while (in != 0) {
    digits.push_back(in % 7);
    in /= 7;
}

std::cout<<"!!/blame\u180E ";
for (auto it = digits.rbegin(); it != digits.rend(); ++it) {
    std::cout << blameStrings[*it];

}
std::cout<<"a\n";
```

Comment: answer[answer.size()] is defined for strings

Comment: @RiaD: You are right, I'll fix that part. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 6):

```
    int digit;
    std::string stringDigit, answer, instring;
    std::cin>>instring;
    int in = std::stoi(instring,nullptr);
```

Declare variables as you need them.

Every file should be self-sufficient.  Make sure you `#include` the headers for components you are using.  Do not rely on implicit inclusion.

Check that `std::cin` successfully read a value from the stream.

Rather than jumping through the hoop of `std::stoi` conversion, just read the value as an integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int in;
    if (!(std::cin >> in)) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid user-id";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

---

```
    while (in != 0){
        digit = in % 7;
        if (digit < 10){
            stringDigit = '0' + digit;
        }else{
            stringDigit = digit - 10 + 'A';
        }
            answer = stringDigit + answer;
            in /= 7;
    }
```

Use symbolic constants instead of magic constants (`'0'`, `'A'`, `7`).

If you are taking a modulus of 7, `digit` will never be greater than 7.  The `else` branch is never taken.

---

Keep functions short and simple.  Each function should perform a single logical operation.  Functions then become simpler to understand, test, and reuse.

You find the remainders, format them to ASCII, unformat them back to the remainders (indices), then format them to your own custom format.  Just save the intermediate remainders and map to your own values.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int read_int(std::istream& in) {
  // ...
}

std::vector<int> itoa_unformatted(int number, int base) {
  // ...
}

int main() {
  constexpr auto mappings = std::make_array("\u180E", "\u200B", "\u200C", "\u200D", 
                                            "\u2060", "\u2063", "\uFEFF");

  auto user_id = read_int(std::cin);
  auto digits = itoa_unformatted(user_id, mappings.size());
  transform(digits, std::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ""),
            [&mappings](auto index) { return mappings[index]; });
  std::cout << "a\n";
}
```

*Note - Example code for **exposition only**.  `std::make_array` and `std::make_ostream_joiner` are part of C++20 (Library Fundamentals V2).  `transform` is just a helper for `std::transform` over a container.  If you would like to play with these features now on gcc/clang, see [mnmlstc core](https://github.com/mnmlstc/core).*

If your base is never going to change, you don't need a generalized base conversion solution then.  The base conversion could be specialized for your specific use case, from sizing the appropriate buffer to strength reducing the expensive operations (like division/modulus).  Always measure before optimizing.

Comment: 'A' and '0' are not really 'magic constants' at all - they *are* the nice symbolic names for 65 and 48 (plus they work even if the compiler's character set is not ASCII).

Comment: On the other hand, I suppose it's *possible* there's a charset out there where '0'..'9' aren't contiguous.

Comment: @WillCrawford https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416926/are-the-character-digits-0-9-required-to-have-contiguous-numeric-values?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @RiaD thank you :o) although it doesn’t guarantee that *all* charsets have to have the 'digits' contiguous, just the "source and execution **basic** character sets" [emphasis mine], though I would guess that means as long as you never call any locale functions you’re good to go?

Comment: What’s the purpose of make_array rather than an aggregate initializer?  Esp in 17 with class template arg deduction.

Comment: @JDługosz I'm honestly just used to using `make_array`. The last time I looked at the provided template deduction guide for `array`, it required all types be the same otherwise it was ill-formed.  `make_array` utilizes `common_type`.  Aggregate initializer is fine.

Comment: @Snowhawk http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides  hmm, it says "equivalent of `make_array`" but then says "ill-formed if not `is_same_v`⋯".  But `make_array` is still in the `experimental::` namespace and not part of the standard.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @JDługosz `std::make_array` is C++20.  I thought Library Fundamentals V2 made 17.  We use 14 but have our own library that supports future library features (similar to [Mnmlstc](https://github.com/mnmlstc/core)).

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this just to give a full round improvement summary, plus I found a few improvements myself, but please remember these mainly are not my improvements. Vote the other answers up! This code was shortened to nearly 1/3 of its size!

## Final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    int in;
    std::string answer;
    std::cin>>in;
    std::string blameStrings[] = {
        "\u180E", "\u200B", "\u200C", "\u200D", "\u2060", "\u2063", "\uFEFF"
    };
    while (in != 0) {
        answer.insert(0,blameStrings[(in % 7)]);
        in /= 7;
    }
    std::cout<<"!!/blame\u180E "<<answer<<"a\n";
}
```

## Line by line:

I'm only going explain code I changed. You can visit (and upvote) the other answers for their explanations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

The additional `#include` was suggested by Snowhawk.

```
int main(){
    int in;
    std::string answer;
    std::cin>>in;
```

The removal of extra variables was suggested by both Snowhawk and Martin R. The removal of `stoi` was suggested by Snowhawk. I also personally removed a few extra variables.

```
    std::string blameStrings[] = {
        "\u180E", "\u200B", "\u200C", "\u200D", "\u2060", "\u2063", "\uFEFF"
    };
```

The array was suggested by Martin R.

```
    while (in != 0) {
        answer.insert(0,blameStrings[(in % 7)]);
        in /= 7;
    }
```

This part of the code was suggested by Martin R. However, I saw that there was a loop iterating through what the first loop had created, so I cut the second loop out.

```
    std::cout<<"!!/blame\u180E "<<answer<<"a\n";
}
```

This just outputs everything in one simple call to the `std::cout`.

Remember, most of these aren't my improvements, so make sure you upvote the answers that the improvements came from.

Comment: Prepending to a string is possibly the most expensive way to modify it.  I know the strings are small, but it still makes me shudder!

Answer (score 3):

### Missing header

We need to include `<string>` to get declarations for `std::string` and `std::stoi`.

### Compile with warnings enabled

You say you don't need any compilation flags.  Whilst that's true (providing your compiler defaults to C++11 or later), it's best to enable some warning flags.  That helps identify defects such as this:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++ 191455.cpp -o 191455
orig.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
orig.cpp:20:26: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
     while(answer.length()>=i){
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Although the mismatch won't cause an actual bug, it can be trivially fixed simply by changing `i` to an unsigned type.  Future readers can then be more confident about your code if you don't leave traps such as that.

### Just read from input

There's little to be gained by reading into a string and then calling `std::stoi()` without checking the end pointer.  Just stream directly into the integer.

### <s>Don't write your own code to convert to octal</s>

<s>That's why we have the `std::oct` stream manipulator.</s>

### Don't add `'0'` to turn numbers into digits and then subtract it again

Either change the `case` to switch on the digits (e.g. `case '0':`, etc), or work directly with small integers.  I prefer the latter, as we can use a simple array to look up the output characters.

### Use `for` to show looping over elements

Consider this loop:

```
int i = 0;
while(answer.length()>=i){
    //...
    i++;
}
```

That's more idiomatically written as:

```
for (int i = 0;  i <= answer.length();  ++i)
```

The off-by-one error becomes more obvious.  Better to avoid that by iterating over the characters:

```
for (auto c: answer)
```

### Don't use narrow streams for wide characters

If we're printing wide-character strings, we should be writing to `std::wcout` rather than to `std::cout`.

### Add some unit tests

Enough said.

---

## Replacement code

With no specification, I can't check whether the output is *correct*, but it produces the same output as the original code for the given test case (301688), as demonstrated by the built-in self-test.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::wstring encode(unsigned long userid)
{
    static wchar_t const code[7] = {
        L'\u180E', // 0 => MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
        L'\u200B', // 1 => ZERO WIDTH SPACE
        L'\u200C', // 2 => ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
        L'\u200D', // 3 => ZERO WIDTH JOINER
        L'\u2060', // 4 => WORD JOINER
        L'\u2063', // 5 => INVISIBLE SEPARATOR
        L'\uFEFF', // 6 => ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE
    };

    std::vector<wchar_t> octalid;
    for (auto i = userid;  i;  i/=7) {
        octalid.push_back(code[i % 7]);
    }

    return L"!!/blame\u180E "
        + std::wstring(octalid.rbegin(), octalid.rend())
        + L"a\n";
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 1) {
        // no arguments - run self tests
        return
            + (encode(0) != L"!!/blame\u180E a\n")
            + (encode(1) != L"!!/blame\u180E \u200Ba\n")
            + (encode(6) != L"!!/blame\u180E \uFEFFa\n")
            + (encode(7) != L"!!/blame\u180E \u200B\u180Ea\n")
            + (encode(8) != L"!!/blame\u180E \u200B\u200Ba\n")
            + (encode(301688) != L"!!/blame\u180E \u200C\u200D\uFEFF\u2060\u200D\uFEFF\u200Ca\n");
    }

    std::locale::global(std::locale{""});

    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        try {
            std::size_t pos;
            unsigned long userid = std::stoul(argv[i], &pos);
            if (argv[i][pos])
                throw std::invalid_argument("not a number");
            std::wcout << encode(userid);
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "Invalid argument: " << argv[i]
                      << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can officially blame that on [quartata](https://stackexchange.com/users/6109921/quartata).